# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have code doing numerical optimization (large program). In gdb it exits with

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
[Switching to process 8673 thread 0x1203]
0x00007fff95d2a9fb in small_malloc_from_free_list ()
```

During backtrace I am told that the following line contains the error, but can't figure out what's wrong.

```
177     U  = calloc(cols*cols,sizeof(double));
```

The code containing that line is

```
int fcn_invXX(double *X, int rows, int cols, double *invXX)
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Declarations
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    // Counters and info
    int i, j, info;

    // Upper triangular placeholder, U, and X'X
    double *U, *XX;

    // Indicator for upper triangular
    char s;

    // Alpha and beta for matrix multiplication - see dgemm documentation
    double alpha, beta;


    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Memory Allocation
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    U  = calloc(cols*cols,sizeof(double));
    XX = calloc(cols*cols,sizeof(double));


    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Compute inverse of X'X
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    alpha = 1.0;
    beta  = 0.0;

    // Get X'X
    cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasTrans, CblasNoTrans, cols, cols, rows, alpha, X, rows, X, rows, beta, XX, cols);
    // CblasColMajor means that data are ordered in columns first, so if X is 4x4, X[0] and X[1] are first column
    // CblasTrans means that the matrix should be transposed before multiplication. Here first matrix is transposed
    // CblasNoTrans means that matrix should not be transposed. Here second matrix is not transposed
    // X is the first matrix, and here, also the second
    // XX stores the product

    for (i = 0; i < cols*cols; i++)
    {
        U[i] = XX[i];
    }

    // Upper Cholesky factorization
    s = 'U'; // upper
    dpotrf_(&s, &cols, U, &cols, &info);
    // info = LAPACKE_dpotrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, s, cols, U, cols);

    for (i = 0; i < cols*cols; i++)
    {
        invXX[i] = U[i];
    }

     // Get inverse
    dpotri_(&s, &cols, invXX, &cols, &info);
    // info = LAPACKE_dpotri(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, s, cols, invXX, cols);

    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (i > j)
            {
                invXX[i + j * cols] = invXX[j + i * cols];
            }
        }
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Free Memory
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    free(U);
    free(XX);

    return info;

}
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: If that really is the line, that obviously ought not happen. Can you get C library symbols to see more trace? Is that a realistic allocation - calloc allocates then frees, and malloc returns null if it can't alloc so a broken calloc implementation might not check that and attempt to zero the memory at null. But that really ought not happen. Which compiler and platform?

Comment: Actually it could also mean that elsewhere you're corrupting the memory allocation 'arena headers' that the C lib uses to track the contents of its heap pools. Could you be writing nulls where you ought not elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know much about C, but maybe small_malloc_from_free_list() is a clue, and you're passing a NULL to free()?

Comment: @LeeLouviere Passing `NULL` for `free` It should be fine.

Comment: @Rup Compiler: gcc, platform: OS X

Comment: @Rup The code calls this function insode an OpenMP loop, and it after a variable amount of iterations - sometimes many, sometimes few - but always at the same place. Newb alert: what are the C library symbols?

Comment: I mean the debugging information and sources for your C library so you can see the actual C statement that's failing. I don't know what that would be for Mac sorry, or even if they're available. My best guess is that you've got a buffer overflow in some other allocated pool of memory and you're writing nulls past the end, but I wouldn't know how to prove that. You could watch the process memory in top or similar to see if it is running out of memory which might trigger problems too (but not necessarily this).

Comment: What value has `cols` at that point? I suspect `cols * cols == 0`. When called with a 0 argument, `calloc` may return a null pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yeah, I should've known that.

Comment: @DanielFischer cols is always 21. The code runs fine on my Linux machine.